# Load a ligher webpage by calculating TTFB

Tags: javascript, pageload

So I want to load a lighter version of a webpage based on the internet connectivity.I was thinking that TTFB (Time to first byte) is a good metric to start with but JavaScript becomes active only after part of the request has been sent from server.

So I was wondering, is there any measurable metric to do this task of loading the alternate version of the page based on internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a tiny landing page, that calculates TTFB and maybe even approximates bandwidth, and then redirects to either the main site or a lighter version of the site based on the resulting information.

They would normally only suffer this minor additional load once as they enter the site, but could be sent back if the session indicated that this check hasn't been done.